# corrupted Excel file from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, corrupt

When I try to save these three dataframes to excel is corrupts somehow and I dont know why. The weird part is that the exact same code works perfectly in `.ipynb` format but does this in `.py`

**The error message from Excel looks like this**

Excel cannot open the file "myfile.xlsx' because the file format or the file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

**My code looks like this**

```
 with pd.ExcelWriter("C:/path/to/folder.xlsx") as writer:
                a_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="a", index=False)
                b_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="b", index=False)
                c_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="c", index=False)
```

Why? and how can this be fixed/avoided?

Comment: First thing I would try is to write those to three individual files.  Not sure it would help but that would be my first step.

Comment: Try specifying the engine parameter, maybe it is defaulting to xlwt

Comment: No venv so that shouldn't be the problem
@Warcupine im reading up on how xlsxwriter works, is it possible to store different df's in sheets with xlsxwriter?

Comment: I've never used xlsxwriter, I usually do openpyxl, but presumably.